# Joomla schedule plugin activation

Tags: joomla, offline, schedule

I have a problem for a long time about having my Joomla site go in offline mode in certain part of the week. I want to make in unaccesable to users for example thursday 12pm to friday 12pm. Is there some kind of plugin or something that can schedule such task? (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I elaborate on Sergey's answer.

You could write a system plugin as I explain below, it won't take long. I'm not sure whether it exists already.

Instead of putting the site offline, your plugin can redirect output to the page you desire and clear the document content, or even load a different template.

With such behaviour, the site will be online or offline depending exclusively on the plugin, thus you need not worry about scheduling actions.

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible to create plugin. plugin is triggered only i someone access site. If no one access then it will still be online. That half of the problem. You may put it offline as soon as first visitor try to access with certain timeframe. But after site is offline plugin will not be triggered anymore, so you cannot put it online.

The only option to automate is to write small PHP script that alter `configuration.php` file and change its `offline` parameter to 1. And then schedule this script in Cron.